# iterate through a list or set in python

Tags: python-3.x

I get one PR view comment to refer me to use set not list under the for loop, anyone know why? since I am sure there is no duplicated element from my list

```py
for i in ['nam1', 'name2']:
#comment for i in {'name1', 'name2'}:
    #do thing on i no matter the sequence about name1 or name2
```

Comment: Why don't you ask the commenter?

Comment: I think you can rephrase this question into something like "list vs sets in python" to make it less opinion based, but then again that question has been asked and answered several times

Answer (score 1):

In some circumstances python is optimizing `set`s into `frozenset`s on its own if it can detect it as "constant" - f.e. for

```
if a in  {"a","b","c"}: 
    pass
```

the `{"a","b","c"}` will be optimized to be a frozenset which is cheaper then a regular set.

---

[3.2 optimizations](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations)

> Python’s peephole optimizer now recognizes patterns such `x in {1, 2, 3}` as being a test for membership in a set of constants. The
>   optimizer recasts the set as a frozenset and stores the pre-built
>   constant

But this is for conditions, not loops ...

---

Lists, sets and frozensets have different time and space demands. `set`s have more overhead then a pure list and will take more time to create them as well as more space to store it.

If you are *sure* that your source data has no duplicates and you do not need to do any lookups where `set`s shine, *list* is fine as is.

If in doubt, measure:

```
import timeit

for size in (4,40,400,4000,40000,400000,):
    # using ints, so string-creation does not overrule container creation
    def create_list():       return list(range(size))
    def create_set():        return set (range(size)) 
    def create_frozen():     return frozenset (range(size)) 
    print(f"list      ({size:>6}): ", timeit.timeit(create_list,   number=100))
    print(f"set       ({size:>6}): ", timeit.timeit(create_set,    number=100))
    print(f"frozenset ({size:>6}): ", timeit.timeit(create_frozen, number=100))

list      (     4):  6.404200030374341e-05 
set       (     4):  8.520600022166036e-05
frozenset (     4):  6.208299964782782e-05   # win

list      (    40):  7.895299950178014e-05   # win
set       (    40):  0.00012057100047968561
frozenset (    40):  0.00011847200039483141

list      (   400):  0.0003935449994969531   # win
set       (   400):  0.0009299020002799807
frozenset (   400):  0.0009138610002992209

list      (  4000):  0.007811448000211385    # win
set       (  4000):  0.013984612000058405
frozenset (  4000):  0.01376037299996824

list      ( 40000):  0.10312434200022835     # win
set       ( 40000):  0.16045320600005653
frozenset ( 40000):  0.15907835799953318

list      (400000):  1.3602663640003811      # win
set       (400000):  2.2382532829997217
frozenset (400000):  2.238473141999748
```